# How do I screen contributors in a Subversion pre-commit hook based on folder?

Tags: svn, hook

Here's the dilemma:

I have a folder structure:

product/branches/stable
product/branches/someotherbranch
product/tags
product/trunk

I have two users: John and Joe.

I want to prevent Joe from committing to:
product/branches/stable
and
product/tags

**What is the *pre-commit hook syntax* in Perl or Bash or whatever to get the job done?**

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use access limitations?
Edit your authz file:

```
[/product/branches/stable product/]
Joe = r
John = rw
```

It is much easier and less error prone(eg restructuring your repo layout)

Comment: Cool, but, I'd prefer to do this in a pre-commit hook if possible.

Comment: @randy - Why?  What does a pre-commit hook buy you that this does not?

Comment: I've got 100's of folders in real life. It requires too much explanation here, but basically, I need to say "if a folder contains some-word, only allow user joe and jane to commit" - however, the folders are added and removed frequently. We have an established naming convention and do NOT have free access to the server since it's in a production environment managed by an IT group. Access requires bureaucracy and red tape. So we're stuck with pattern matching for changing folder structures and users. I figured this would be a common problem for an SCM in a large swdev shop.

Comment: By 'free access' I mean shell / SSH access.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-commit hook script is called with two arguments that you can use with `svnlook` to get more details on the transaction about to be performed.

For example, if %1 and %2 are your hook script arguments,

```
svnlook author %1 -t %2
```

gives the author, and

```
svnlook dirs-changed %1 -t %2
```

gives all the directories involved. There are other commands of course, as you can see in the [SVN online book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnlook).

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider integrating your repo with LDAP and use permissions to control access